# Software updater says "An unhandlable error occured"

Tags: dpkg, update-manager, steam, read-only

The problem started when I was trying to update a game on steam. The game couldn't be updated because it had a "disk write error" so I just rebooted the system, then steam wanted to update itself but after some time downloading the update it said there was a network problem and I clearly was connected to my WiFi, I even tried by cable and said the same thing, b.t.w. my router was working perfectly I tried on other devices and the Internet worked.

So I thought that maybe I needed to use sofware updater, and it was working well until some point where it says "An unhandlable error occurred. there seems to be a programming error in aptdaemon, the software that allows you to install/remove software and to perform other packagement related tasks".
I have also tried using "sudo apt-get update" but it says:

```
sudo: unable to open /var/lib/sudo/sebas411/0: No such file or directory
Ignhttp://dl.google.com stable InRelease
Ign http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
E: Couldn't create temporary file to work with /var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_Release - mkstemp (30: Read-only file system)
W: Not using lockingfor read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem
```

I also can't open firefox  and steam now says: "Fatal error: failed to save package manifest"

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You possibly have a hard disk problem. It's errored, and it's placed itself in read only mode. I'd do the following to check the file system, fix possible dpkg errors, and check for errors in syslog:

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose `Advanced Options`
- choose `Recovery mode`
- choose `root` access
- type `fsck -f /` # to check the file system
- run fsck more than once if there were errors
- type `sudo mount -o rw,remount /` # to remount root as read/write
- type `sudo dpkg --configure -a` # to fix broken dpkg
- type `sudo apt-get install -f` # to finish upgrades
- optional commands to check syslog for sda errors

  - `cd /var/log`
  - `grep sda syslog*`
- type `reboot`
- once back in Ubuntu, run the `Software Updater`

Comment: I opened recovery mode but there is no text input, I have to choose with the arrow keys but when I select fsck it says I have to run it manually, how do I do it?

Comment: Oops, I forgot a step! My bad. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I ran fsck and fixed the errors that appeared, then I remounted as read/write but when I typed sudo dpkg --configure -a I got this: https://imgur.com/R2aijJz

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre-headless`, then start at dpkg step again and continue.

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you, but it now says this: https://imgur.com/jl1vPpQ

Comment: Try the `sudo apt-get install -f` step.

Comment: I have tried that too but it says the same when it tries to install openjdk-6-jre-headless

Comment: Lets skip ahead to the optional commands to check syslog. Look for errors on sda.

Comment: I got this: https://imgur.com/WQNxmPP

Comment: Two steps. Type `exit` and that should take you back to the menu where you chose root access. This time choose `dpkg` and lets see if it can fix the errors. When it's done, reboot to Ubuntu, and try and run Software Updater. If that doesn't all work, then we may have to wait for a dpkg expert to help you more. Keep me posted by starting new comments to me by starting them with `@heynnema`.

Comment: It now says the package system is broken, thanks anyway. I will keep you updated

Comment: Yes, we knew the package system is broken. And the disk had errors. That's what the commands that I gave you were supposed to fix... but there's more wrong... and it's more than my expertise can provide. Sorry. Hopefully somebody will chime in with the final fix.

Comment: The strange thing is that I have a dual-boot and windows is working perfectly, maybe it's Linux's partition. If I cannot find a solution I will format the partition and reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: It works!!! I just had to run sudo apt-get install -f once booted instead of using it on recovery mode. Thank you for all the help

Comment: Great news! Glad you got it going!